# Объединение меток «цвета» и «color»

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

[цвета](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0) — [15 вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0), [color](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/color) — [34 вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/color). Вероятно, стоит объединить как синонимы.

Comment: мне кажется стоит вообще их удалить

Comment: @Grundy, если вроде [такого](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Village_pump_%28technical%29#Some_X_11_color_names_not_supported_in_all_browsers) прозвучал бы вопрос, к примеру, «Как узнать, какими браузерами поддерживается X 11 color `RebeccaPurple`?» — мне кажется, одна из них пришлась бы к месту. Спасибо.

Comment: не соглашусь, даже в этом вопросе смысла эта метка не несет

Comment: Вероятно, нам нужно *Стереть яркие [цвета]* и *Vanish that [color]*

Comment: @СашаЧерных это вопрос про [tag:css] и [tag:кроссбраузерность].

Answer (score 5):

## Синонимизировать, но не удалять.

Метка применима к вопросам, где речь идёт о действиях с цветами или графикой, например, алгоритм наложения цветов, формат записи цвета и т. д.

Comment: "Формат записи цвета" всё же не стоит относить к самому цвету: это вопрос скорее про технологию, в которой цвет употреблён, т. к. формат специфичен для неё (даже если реализован в нескольких местах). А вот смешивание цветов, преобразования, цветовые модели -- это да, годится. Правда, если закрепить тематику так, придётся из здоровой доли вопросов эти метки поубирать `:]`

Comment: @D-side, но ведь поубирать неправильно расставленные метки - это логично?

Comment: Логично, но если получится, что неактуальной становится *большая часть вопросов*, это повод поставить под вопрос правильность определения тематики этой метки. Если у людей эта метка ассоциируется "немного не с тем". Хотя мне кажется, что это не тот случай.

Comment: @D-side, у нас всего 15+34-2 = 47 вопросов.

Comment: Больше 42-х :-)

Comment: Теперь можно и самому.

Answer (score 4):

Обе метки стоит удалить, они несут не больше пользы чем метки [текст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82) и [шрифт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82)

Comment: Хотя существует [11 тысяч вопросов на Stack Overflow на английском](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colors) с меткой «colors», соглашусь, какой–то смысловой нагрузки она не вносит.

Comment: А как же работа с цветовыми моделями? )